# how to make ellipsis work with display flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox, ellipsis

I don't know why this simple CSS isn't working...

```css
.app{
 display: flex;
cursor: pointer;
}
.test{
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  max-width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid navy;
  min-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <div class="test">Test Test Test Test Test Test  </div>
</div>
```

I want ellipsis work with the property `display:flex` i traied minwidth =0 but it doesnt work

Comment: Did you mean to actually put the `display: flex` on the surrounding `<dvi>`?

Comment: display :flex is on div parent let s say

Comment: Then please [edit] your question. Currently the selector is targeting the `<a>`nchor element itself

Comment: Thanks for your edit, but now the `.app a` selector matches no element at all

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `inline` properties for `flex` component. You can wrap your text by inline component, `span` for example.

```css
.app{
cursor: pointer;
}
.test{
  display: flex;
  max-width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid navy;
  min-width: 0;
}
.text{
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <div class="test"><span class="text">Test Test Test Test Test Test</span></div>
</div>
```